# UniswapV3 Get unclaimed fees

Tags: uniswap, swaps

[image]

How can the unclaimed fees (see green rectangle of the screen shot) being retrieved calling the UniswapV3 contracts or the Uniswap sdk-v3?

I want to show the total liquidity invested (each pair) including the accrued fees.

Comment: In your pasted code many of the variables are not recognised.
Could you please add the correct missing imports at the top of the pasted code?
That would be a great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution to get the liquidity and accrued unclaimed fees from a Uniswap V3 position:

```js
const { Pool } = require("@uniswap/v3-sdk");
const { Position } = require("@uniswap/v3-sdk");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const { BigNumber } = require("@ethersproject/bignumber");

const MAX_UINT128 = BigNumber.from(2).pow(128).sub(1);

/* GET POSITION LIQUIDITY */
const USDEURPool = new Pool(tokenUSD, 
                            tokenEUR, 
                            Number.parseInt(immutables.fee), 
                            state.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), 
                            state.liquidity.toString(), 
                            Number.parseInt(state.tick) );
const positionInfo = await positionmanagerContract.positions(1058);
const position = new Position({pool: USDEURPool, liquidity: positionInfo.liquidity.toString(), tickLower: positionInfo.tickLower, tickUpper: position.tickUpper});
console.log("amount0:", position.amount0.toSignificant(4));
console.log("amount1:", position.amount1.toSignificant(4));
// get more details such as currency infos from position, such as token symbol, etc.

/* GET ACCRUED UNCLAIMDED FEES */
// callStatic simulates a call without state changes
var results = await positionmanagerContract.callStatic.collect({tokenId: 1058,
                                                                recipient: owner, 
                                                                amount0Max: MAX_UINT128, 
                                                                amount1Max: MAX_UINT128}, {from: owner});
console.log("Fee0:",parseFloat(results.amount0)/100);
console.log("Fee1:",parseFloat(results.amount1)/100);
```